# python ipaddr library netmask IPv6

Tags: python, ipv6

I'm using the python-ipaddr library.

I'm not able to specify the netmask for `IPv6` addresses.It only needs a `CIDR` notation.

```
>>> ipaddr.IPv6Network('2001:db00::0/24')
IPv6Network('2001:db00::/24')
>>> ipaddr.IPv6Network('2001:db00::0/ffff:ff00::')
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ipaddr.py", line 1925, in __init__
   raise NetmaskValueError(addr[1])
ipaddr.NetmaskValueError: ffff:ff00::
```

Is there a way to use `netmask` for IPv6 addresses instead of `CIDR`?
If not, are there any python libraries that support this?
What's the most pythonic way of converting `netmask` to `CIDR` for `IPv6`

TIA

Comment: FYI, the IPv6 address range reserved for documentation, which you should use for things like this question, is `2001:DB8::/32'. You were so close...

Comment: reserved for documentation?

Comment: See [RFC 3849, IPv6 Address Prefix Reserved for Documentation](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3849). This range is not allowed to be routed, and should be used for various purposes, including things like demonstrating something where you don't want to use a valid IPv6 address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CIDR is the only official way specify a subnet in IPv6.

So there are probably no libraries supporting this.

But you can count bits and convert it to CIDR with the bit-count as the suffix.

```
mask = "ffff:fff0::"
bitCount = [0, 0x8000, 0xc000, 0xe000, 0xf000, 0xf800, 0xfc00, 0xfe00, 0xff00, 0xff80, 0xffc0, 0xffe0, 0xfff0, 0xfff8, 0xfffc, 0xfffe, 0xffff]

count = 0
try:
  for w in mask.split(':'):
    if not w or int(w, 16) == 0: break
    count += bitCount.index(int(w, 16))
except:
  raise SyntaxError('Bad NetMask')
```

Answer (score 2):

IPv6 doesn't use net masks anymore, always CIDR notation. CIDR notation is also very common with IPv4 as it is much easier to deal with than those clumsy netmasks :)